# How can I upload a CodeIgniter project to heroku?

Tags: codeigniter, heroku, codeigniter-3, cleardb

I need to upload my project to Heroku. I have installed ClearDB mysql add-on to my app. But I don't know how my codeigniter will work on heroku? How can I upload my existing database fro localhost to live heroku? Can any1 guide me?

Comment: I guess it can be deployed like a normal php app https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-php

Comment: @kawadhiya21 but how do I connect it to database?